# Which merge strategies does mercurial use?

Tags: git, mercurial, merge

I work in an environment with large scale multi-parallel branching. Looking at GIT I see it has several merge strategies:

```
already up-to-date
fast-forward
octopus
resolve
recursive
```

Does Mercurial have the equivalent of each of these? (ie is the implementation of Mercurial's merge algorithm as good as recursive?

Comment: `already up-to-date` and `fast-forward` aren't merge strategies. There are, though, `ours` and `subtree`.

Comment: Also of interest: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/what-is-the-algorithm-or-decision-process-used-by-mercurial-during-merge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- already up-to-date
- fast-forward

Those aren't merge strategies, I guess the first one is when there's nothing to merge (obviously supported). The second isn't a merge, updating in hg is equivalent to fast-forward (there's nothing to merge).

- octopus

Doesn't apply to mercurial, merges are always between two heads.

- resolve

That's the default merge strategies.

- recursive

Could probably be done with a custom merge script (`hg`, like `git` just call external tools to handle the merge). But nobody seemed interested in it for now, maybe because it doesn't bring a lot of improvements compared to resolve.

Comment: "fast-forward" is not rebase: is actually the opposite of "up-to-date", in a sense that current branch is ancestor of merged branch.  By default (i.e. no `--no-ff` option) Git just advances branch head instead of performing pointless merge.

Comment: "recursive" merge strategy was designed to deal with criss-cross merges and other situations with more than one merge base.... and with renames in such situation.

Comment: @Jakub, thanks I updated the part about fast-forward. So it's just "update" in mercurial.

does the recursive strategy make a difference in practice?